# How to run CRUD in single procedure by using json?(T-SQL)

Tags: json, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpProductTsk]
    (@json varchar(MAX))
AS
    ----insert---
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SelectedProcedure varchar(max) = ''

    IF @SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductIns'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product](ProductName, ProductCategory, InsertPersonId, InsertDate)
            SELECT 
                p.productName, p.productCategory,
                p.insertPersonId, GETDATE()
            FROM
                OPENJSON(@json)
            WITH
                (productName varchar(50) '$.ProductName',
                 productCategory varchar(50) '$.ProductCategory',
                 insertPersonId int '$.InsertPersonId',
                 insertDate datetime '$.InsertDate') AS p

        ----SELECT-----
        IF @SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductSelect'
        BEGIN
            SELET p.productName, p.productCategory 
            FROM [dbo].[Product] AS p
            FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('ProductDetails')
        END

        -----UPDATE-----
        IF @SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductUpd'
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ProductId int,
                    @ProductName varchar(50),
                    @ProductCategory varchar(50),
                    @InsertPersonId int

            SELECT 
                @ProductId = p.productId,
                @ProductName = p.productName,
                @ProductCategory = p.productCategory,
                @InsertPersonId = p.insertPersonId
            FROM
                OPENJSON (@Json)
            WITH
                (productId int '$.ProductId',
                 productName varchar(50) '$.ProductName',
                 productCategory varchar(50) '$.ProductCategory',
                 insertPersonId int '$.InsertPersonId') AS p

            UPDATE [dbo].[Product]
            SET productName = @ProductName,
                productCategory = @ProductCategory,
                insertPersonId = @InsertPersonId
            WHERE ProductId = @ProductId
        END

        ----Delete---
        IF @SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductDel'
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Id int

            SELECT @Id = p.productId
            FROM OPENJSON(@json)
            WITH (productId int '$.ProductId') AS p

            DELETE FROM [dbo].[Product]
            WHERE ProductId = @Id
        END
    END
END

EXEC [dbo].[SpProductTsk] @json = '{
    "SelectedProcedur":"SpProductIn",
    "ProductName":"Mutton",
    "ProductCategory":"Meat",
    "InsertPersonId":"1",
    "InsertDate":"" }'

SELECT * FROM product
```

Code compiles but shows 0 rows inserted

Comment: I **strongly** doubt SQL Server **2005** had an `OPENJSON` method .... - please update your tags to the actual version you're using

Comment: for starters openjson wasn't introduced until sql server 2016 as previous comment indicated, please update your tags.  Second, you declare and set '@SelectedProcedure' to blank and then your very next statement is IF '@SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductIns' will always end up being false so it will never end up executing anything.

Comment: Also - this "one stored procedure to do everything" might look really smart and nifty at first - but these tend to become unwieldy and hard to maintain. I would recommend to have **one procedure per operation** - and then you can have each procedure doing exactly **one thing only** and take only those parameters really needed. It's called the **Single Reponsibility Principle** and is one of the basic mainstays of good system design

Comment: @TimMylott what is exact way to make selected procedeure readable while executing stored procedure?

Comment: @marc_s as per your recommendation, i had already completed it. But i have now next requirement so i m applying this method

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  How is your stored procedure supposed to know SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductSelect' or SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductUpd' etc to execute that particular block of code?  As it stands you are explicitly setting the value of SelectProcedure to blank and it will never equal one of those values.

Comment: @TimMylott yeah I changed it. while checking by if else condition, procedure redirects to else and throws an error. It does not insert to if statement. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the "SelectedProcedur" value from the json you pass into the stored procedure.

After to declare @SelectedProcedure set it to the "SelectedProcedur" value from the json you pass in.

```
DECLARE @SelectedProcedure VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @SelectedProcedure = (
                             SELECT [value]
                             FROM   [OPENJSON](@json)
                             WHERE  [key] = 'SelectedProcedur'
                         );
```

You'll need to fix your  if statements as well. All your code is inside the "IF @SelectedProcedure = 'SpProductIns'" block so none of the other if statements would ever get executed.

Before the line

> ----SELECT-----

add

> END

and then remove one of the **END** at the bottom.